# How to use GRAPHIC 20-band equalizer effect that adjusts OVER TIME, instead of using the default 5-band parametric EQ?

Tags: adobe-audition

I need to apply 20-band graphic EQ effect to a clip, but I want it to be applied gradually over time instead of just sitting there at a constant setting for the entire clip.

I've learned how to do something similar with the EQ that is "built-in" into the multitrack session, it's a 5-band parametric EQ. The problem is, I need 20-band graphic EQ, and I want EACH band to gradually work its way from a starting number to the target number (or at least all bands from the same starting number to the same target number).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've never used Audition, but knowing how to do it in other editors I found this - https://helpx.adobe.com/audition/using/automating-mixes-envelopes1.html - look for the keyframes section.

Comment: Why not use a parametric EQ to deal with the desire for more bands?

Comment: @ToddWilcox, I think that's what I eventually will have to do: create as many copies of the same clip as there are bands in the graphic EQ, load them into the multitrack and use parametric EQ on each clip (adjusting mhz/khz properly), imitating each band of the graphic EQ. Then all 20 clips would hopefully sound as expected. But I thought there must be a better way.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for the link, useful info. But Audition, unfortunately, doesn't let you adjust graphic EQ bands using keyframes, it only SOMEWHAT lets you do that with built-in parametric EQ (5 bands).

Comment: You could export the audio to a DAW or editor that has an automation feature, then re-import it into the Audition project.